# Insertion fail with SQL Grammar Exception in Hibernate MySQL 5

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate

I'm working on a project with hibernate technology.
I got my POJO classes from hibernate reveng system, then I tried to test my project set-up with a saving database process. This is where I get my "could not insert: [tables.Users]" error. 
I'll share the necessary classes.
This is saving Database class.

```
static boolean SaveDatabase(Users object) {


    Session session = null;
    try {

        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(object);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            transaction.rollback();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return true;
}
```

My configurations and table classes are correct. This is test class;

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Test RegisterUser and GetUsersWithId in here

    LogIn test = new LogIn();
    Users user = new Users();

    user.setUserEmail("email");
    user.setUserAdress("adres here");
    user.setUserFbId(3);
    test.RegisterUsers(user);
}
}
```

And this is Stack Trace :

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
could not insert: [tables.Users]
```

When run my test program in debug mode session.save(object); line gives an exception and my program jumps into catch block. Also my transaction and session is not null. There are two pics of my debug mode that can help.

[image: My passes class to the database. I'm not familiar with these hashsets, so there could be something wrong.]
[image: Some of the varieble's values when debugging is in catch block. e = SQLGrammarException sent out here]

Thanks for any help.

EDIT 3: Edited Stack trace

```
    Hibernate: insert into mobil.mobil.users (UserFbId, UserFbToken, UserName, UserLastName, UserEmail, UserAdress, UserFavouritedTopicsCount, UserCreatedTopicsCount, UserRecommendedTopicsCount, UserFollowingsCount, UserFollowersCount, UserBio, UserProfilePicUrl, UserIsOnline, UserPoint) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [tables.Users]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2176)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2656)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:563)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:551)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:547)
    at DAO.LogIn.SaveDatabase(LogIn.java:55)
    at DAO.LogIn.RegisterUsers(LogIn.java:16)
    at Test.main(Test.java:14)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.users (UserFbId, UserFbToken, UserName, UserLastName, UserEmail, UserAdress, Us' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
    ... 18 more
```

Hibernate Config. file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="">
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">diobookbla</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mobil</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">mobil</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
        <mapping class="tables.Users" resource="Users.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping class="tables.Topicrecommend" resource="Topicrecommend.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping class="tables.Posts" resource="Posts.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping class="tables.Location" resource="Location.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping class="tables.Topics" resource="Topics.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping class="tables.Favouritetopics" resource="Favouritetopics.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping class="tables.Postlike" resource="Postlike.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping class="tables.Userfollow" resource="Userfollow.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping class="tables.Mention" resource="Mention.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

EDIT 2 : Users.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Dec 11, 2012 4:55:13 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="tables.Users" table="users" catalog="mobil">
        <id name="userId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="UserId" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="userFbId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="UserFbId" />
        </property>
        <property name="userFbToken" type="string">
            <column name="UserFbToken" />
        </property>
        <property name="userName" type="string">
            <column name="UserName" />
        </property>
        <property name="userLastName" type="string">
            <column name="UserLastName" />
        </property>
        <property name="userEmail" type="string">
            <column name="UserEmail" />
        </property>
        <property name="userAdress" type="string">
            <column name="UserAdress" />
        </property>
        <property name="userFavouritedTopicsCount" type="string">
            <column name="UserFavouritedTopicsCount" />
        </property>
        <property name="userCreatedTopicsCount" type="string">
            <column name="UserCreatedTopicsCount" />
        </property>
        <property name="userRecommendedTopicsCount" type="string">
            <column name="UserRecommendedTopicsCount" />
        </property>
        <property name="userFollowingsCount" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="UserFollowingsCount" />
        </property>
        <property name="userFollowersCount" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="UserFollowersCount" />
        </property>
        <property name="userBio" type="string">
            <column name="UserBio" />
        </property>
        <property name="userProfilePicUrl" type="string">
            <column name="UserProfilePicUrl" />
        </property>
        <property name="userIsOnline" type="java.lang.Boolean">
            <column name="UserIsOnline" />
        </property>
        <property name="userPoint" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="UserPoint" />
        </property>
        <set name="topicses" table="topics" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="TopicUserId" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="tables.Topics" />
        </set>
        <set name="mentionsForMentionedId" table="mention" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="MentionedId" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="tables.Mention" />
        </set>
        <set name="favouritetopicses" table="favouritetopics" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="UserId" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="tables.Favouritetopics" />
        </set>
        <set name="mentionsForMentionerId" table="mention" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="MentionerId" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="tables.Mention" />
        </set>
        <set name="postlikes" table="postlike" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="UserId" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="tables.Postlike" />
        </set>
        <set name="userfollowsForFollowingId" table="userfollow" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="FollowingId" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="tables.Userfollow" />
        </set>
        <set name="topicrecommends" table="topicrecommend" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="UserId" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="tables.Topicrecommend" />
        </set>
        <set name="userfollowsForFollowerId" table="userfollow" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="FollowerId" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="tables.Userfollow" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: It is SQLGrammarException, something wrong with query. may be e.printStackTrace() will give more information.

Comment: Do you config pojo mapping xml in hibernate? Post config file.

Comment: I've added stacktrace and Hibernate.config.xml

Comment: <property key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>. the logs will show complete SQL query so that we can analize easy, where the query is wrong

Comment: Should I add the code fragment in hibernate.config.xml @pradeep ?

Comment: yes add it in side session-factory tag

Comment: @pradeep when I add it and run the program, I get this error
"Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration"

Comment: oh sorry <property key="hibernate.show_sql">true</property> use this

Comment: I've use it already :) these are the security errors on the hibernate.config.xml's security tab 
"ERROR: 6:38 Attribute "name" is required and must be specified for element type "property".
ERROR: 6:38 Attribute "key" must be declared for element type "property"."

Comment: yes <property> tag must be end with </property> only, previsoly i have give </prop> , so correct this

Comment: at first I've added <property key="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
it wanted name for property, than I made it 
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" key="hibernate.show_sql">true</property> like this. I still get "Attribute "key" must be declared for element type "property"." error eventhough I declared it in property tags. :/

Comment: Can you post the mapping file Users.hbm.xml please?

Comment: Does the table `mobil.users` exist? (Perhaps you created it in the wrong database?) - You already use the show_sql property. Can you post the complete statement which MySQL does not like?

Comment: mobil.users exist in database, I checked it again. I couldn't get it, what did u mean at MySQL does not like? @johanna

Comment: I mean, in the error message there is only a part of the SQL statement: `.users (UserFbId, UserFbToken, ...`. Please give us the complete SQL statement, which let MySQL throw the error message. It must be in your console output, when you set `hibernate.show_sql` to true (see a comment abouve).

Comment: I've done what you said, and it gave me this sql statement. "Hibernate: insert into mobil.mobil.users (UserFbId, UserFbToken, UserName, UserLastName, UserEmail, UserAdress, UserFavouritedTopicsCount, UserCreatedTopicsCount, UserRecommendedTopicsCount, UserFollowingsCount, UserFollowersCount, UserBio, UserProfilePicUrl, UserIsOnline, UserPoint) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

In here there is two mobil.mobil.users but it must be mobil.users and also my values haven't passed to the insertion because there is lots of ?. How can I solve this issue :)
@johanna

Comment: Also it takes first mobil from users.hbm.xml and second one from hibernate.config.xml 's default schema property. When I delete any of it it becomes .mobil.users or mobil..users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, now I got it, where the problem is. `mobil.mobil.users` is nonsense, `mobil.users` would by correct and also `users` would work, because you have chosen the correct database in the connect string.

You've defined the database name at least three times:

1. In your connect string: `<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mobil</property>`
2. As the default schema: `<property name="hibernate.default_schema">mobil</property>`
3. As catalog in the class mapping: `<class name="tables.Users" table="users" catalog="mobil">`

It is absolutely sufficient to define the database name in the connect string (1.). Both 2. and 3. you can remove; at least one of the two you must remove.

---

One remark to the question marks in the logging: Hibernate never shows the concrete values in the sql log. It always shows question marks. This is due to a JDBC limitation. Nevertheless the correct values are passed to the database. If you want to see the actual values, then you have to use a separate JDBC logging utility like log4jdbc.

Comment: I've been trying to solve this problem for 2 or 3 weeks, thank you and all commenters so much for your attention and help.